# Url key disappearing and visibility changing when saving a product from collection

Tags: product

I'm encountering the problem of the url key being unset and the visibility not retaining its original value when I'm retrieving a product collection, iterating through it to set a value per product, and then saving it as in the following:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setDescription('custom description');
    $product->save();
}
```

However, if I add those attributes to be selected

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('visibility')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
```

Then I'm able to save the product fine, and the url key and visibility retain their values.

A. Is this the correct way to handle this, or is there something else that I am supposed to set before I retrieve the collection?

B. Are there any other product attributes that have this same issue? (I didn't notice any other ones)

Thanks.

Comment: afaik this is a known bug in magento. Which version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Don't save a product from a collection.
A product collection item does not contain all the data for a product. You can end up losing a lot of attribute values if the attribute is not in the collection.
If you want to call `$product->save()` to update a product, just to be on the safe side, first you must call `$product->load()`.

If you want to update just one attribute (or a few of them) use this. It's faster.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    array($productId),
    array('attribute_code'=>$attributeValue),
    $storeId //use '0' for default values
);
```

The code above works for many products at a time, and many attributes at a time.

Comment: No this shouldn't be the case (at least I think so), because the attributes should be checked against `$_origData` and the object is aware of its `$_partialLoaded` status.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt. Not sure, but you may be right. Either way...you shouldn't update products using `->save()`. It's faster using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()`

Comment: I forget this method all the time, thanks for remembering.

Comment: `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes()` may cause some other problems because related events not fire.